# How to configure junest to mount a specific directory to chroot?

Tags: linux

junest automatically mounts `/home/$user/` which is really nice, but I also want to mount for example `/srv/public` or `/mnt/something` so I can use it, inside a junest environment, how could I do this?

Comment: Do you mean using [groot](https://github.com/fsquillace/junest/blob/master/README.md#chroot-based)?

Comment: junest support different backends, linux namespaces, proot, chroot, groot..

Comment: @harrymc ohh, it says there `junest -b "--bind /home/user/mydata /mnt/mydata"`

Comment: thank you, feel free to add as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JuNest readme gives this information that you may use in the
[Bind directories section](https://github.com/fsquillace/junest/blob/master/README.md#bind-directories) :

> **Bind directories**
>
> To bind a host directory to a guest location:
>
> ```
> junest -b "--bind /home/user/mydata /mnt/mydata"
> ```
>
> Or using proot arguments:
>
> ```
> junest proot -b "-b /mnt/mydata:/home/user/mydata"
> ```
>
> The option `-b` to provide options to the backend program will work
> with PRoot, Namespace and GRoot backend programs. Check out the
> backend program options by passing --help option:
>
> ```
> junest [u|g|p] -b "--help"
> ```